# Is it safe to post password without hashing it to django-rest-api?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication, django-authentication

Django forms use CSRF token in the forms and even while making POST to django-rest-api CSRF tokens are used. I have two questions regarding posting password using form without hashing over HTTP connection -

1. Is it safe to post password using django form posting for authentication ?
2. Is it safe to post password to django-rest-api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of hashing a password is to irreversibly hide the original password. Password hashes are stored in a database instead of cleartext password, so that in the event that the database has been compromised by hackers, they will not know the original passwords. This means they might know the usernames, but they will not be able to access those accounts (at least not without investing resources to crack those hashes).

Back to your problem, if you store password hashes, and you want users to submit password hashes, then it defeats the whole purpose since the password hashes will then effectively serve as the cleartext passwords as well.

To answer your question, yes, it is safe to POST cleartext passwords if password hashes are stored in the database. If you want to improve security, use HTTPS so that the cleartext password is encrypted in transit to the server.

**EDIT :**
To clarify, when I said:

> it is safe to POST cleartext passwords if password hashes are stored
>   in the database

I mean it is safe from the attack vector specified in the example above (hackers compromising the database to take control of accounts).

Comment: Anything transmitted in a network in cleartext is never safe (e.g. HTTP). That is why you should use HTTPS so that your HTTP traffic to and from the server will be encrypted, and you will also be alerted to any man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: So there's no way to prevent data sniffing over HTTP ?

Comment: No. HTTP on its own is cleartext traffic. This means all the content you send/request can be seen by someone in the route to the server. You can use Wireshark to verify that. That is why you should use HTTPS, so that everything you send/receive from the server will be encrypted. Is there any particular reason you are sticking with HTTP?